# Convert Coordinate Notation warning, empty output

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, convert, utm

I have the following UTM coordinates:

| ID | Easting | Northing | UTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10V 0614067 | 7080117 | 10V 614067 7080117 |
| 2 | 10V 0614134 | 7080506 | 10V 614134 7080506 |
| 3 | 10V 0614193 | 7080765 | 10V 614193 7080765 |

I have used the Convert Coordinate Notation -tool in ArcGIS Pro to try and convert the coordinates to WGS84. I've followed the instructions by Esri found in here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/supported-notation-formats.htm and used the UTM column as the input field with embedded spaces and latitude band instead of N (or S), no decimals and UTM Zone 10N as the input coordinate system.

I get the warning number 001293: Coordinate conversion failed for  records. Any idea how I should format the UTM coordinates for ArcGIS Pro to recognize them?

Comment: The  `10V` is not part of the easting, it's the MGRS grid cell, so the data isn't UTM, but MGRS.

Comment: The UTM zones are divided into latitude bands as well (each 8 degrees latitude) and marked with letters, that's where I believe the "V" comes from. Eg. in here: https://www.maptools.com/tutorials/grid_zone_details

Comment: Yes, those grid zones are assigned by the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS). The linked document conflates the two incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your three lines of sample data worked for me with

- Input coordinate system: WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_10N
- Input coordinate format: UTM bands
- X Field (where the data is) UTM

[image: Convert Coordinate Notation screenshot]

If the warning is being cause by other records, try ticking the 'Exclude records with invalid notation' option

Comment: Thanks Mark! I tried it again but without a success (the name warning appears with an empty output). Must be something with my data.